# Waiting for a process to block a signal

Tags: linux

I have a process that uses `pthread_sigmask` to block `SIGINT` and `sigwait` to wait on it to handle it manually.

To test this, I start my process, wait some time then send `SIGINT`.

Is there a way to avoid waiting some magic number amount of time here? Can I wait for my process to block a signal?

Comment: It seems like signals may not be the appropriate mechanism. Why not use something like a message queue or semaphore?

Comment: I would be open to other approaches here if this can be done more elegantly. Initially I wanted to be able to `ctrl+c` the process in the console to exit, which requires manually handling `SIGINT`.

Comment: But why are you waiting on it with `sigwait`? SIGINT is not intended to be used for IPC, it's for interrupting a process while it's doing other things. As long as you establish the handler before you do anything that needs to be cleaned up, it should be fine. The sender doesn't need to wait -- if it sends SIGINT too soon, nothing has to be cleaned up, and the process just exits.

Comment: Sending `SIGINT` early is safe, when I need to do work that requires cleanup I spawn a thread that waits on `SIGINT` with `sigwait` to coordinate the exit with the other threads. I want to test the case where it needs to handle it manually and do extra work, so I need to wait until this begins.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think there's a way to tell whether another process has blocked the signal yet. You could use some other kind of IPC for the recipient process to tell the sender process when it's ready.